# NullPointerException when Serializing Nullable joda LocalDate (AVRO)

Tags: java, serialization, avro, kafka-producer-api

I have the following date field declaration in my avro schema which is nullable or optional:

```
{
 "name" : "expiryDate",
 "type" : ["null", {
    "type" : "int",
    "logicalType" : "date"
 }],
 "source" : "element tradingExpiryDate"
},
```

Generating the avro class works well, however, a nullpointerexception is encountered during serialization of the field.

Is there a way on how to handle this?